# I got deadlock when service fabric stateful service

Tags: deadlock, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

GRPC END Contract=IPubSubPartitionManager Action=GetOrAddContextSelectorPartition ID=71eff709-3920-4139-a5c9-2b0bef6f5ba7 From=ipv4:10.0.0.56:35091 IsFault=True Duration(ms)=4932 Request { "contextSelector": "/debug/fabric--madari-madariservice-01-GrpcPublishSubscribeProber-8", "addIfNotExists": true, "clientCredential": { "credentialValue": "uswestcentral-prod.sdnpubsub.core.windows.net-client", "credentialRegex": { "pattern": "null string" }, "enablePropertyBasedAcls": false } } Response { "errorMsg": "Timed out waiting for Shared lock on key; id=49b61cd7-31ba-4c5d-b579-d068326e8a90@133028293161628388@urn:ContextSelectorMapping/dataStore@132077756302731635, timeout=4000ms, txn=133029757743026569, lockResourceNameHash=6572262935404555983; oldest txn with lock=133029757735370545 (mode Shared)\r\n" }

Answer (score 0):

This problem mostly affects read operations that support Repeatable Read, ***the user may request an Update lock rather than a Shared lock.*** Update lock is an asymmetric lock is used to prevent but ***when a several transactions potentially updates at that time deadlock occurs.***

- Try to avoid  `TimeSpan.MaxValue`  for time-outs. It may detect deadlocks.
- Don't create a ***transaction within another transaction's***  `using`  statement. For example: ***the two transactions (T1 and T2) are attempting to read from and update K1, respectively. Due to the fact that they both end up with the Shared lock possible for them to deadlock. In this situation, one or both of the operations will time out***.

To avoid a frequent type of deadlock that arises,

- The default transaction timeout should be increased. Usually, it takes 4 second try to use in a different value
- Make sure the ***transactions are short-lived***; if they last any longer than necessary, ***you'll be blocking other tasks in the queue for a longer period of time than necessary.***

For Reference:  [Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines)